# How  to   open    .png   or  .doc file  in android

Tags: android

How  to   open    .png   or  .doc file  in android  in  new Activity.

Comment: Do you mean how to open a binary stream or how to display them? Please be more specific.

Comment: Ya I want to   read   the content  of  file   and   showing  it  in screen

Comment: Then you do it as in any Java app. Using FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

With PNGs you can use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

There isn't really any way to read DOC files unless you want to write a parser yourself. You could try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), but you'll still have to draw it to the screen yourself.

Comment: An image view can display a .png, how do you load a .png file (which is not a resource)?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was asked a long time a go (Kotlin wasn't even born :) )  but maybe someone will find useful my answer.

If you want to open an image (.png, .jpg, .jpeg) or a file (.doc or .docx) then you could do this:

**JAVA**

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in the `onActivityResult` method:

```
        if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                if (data.getData().toString().contains(".png") ||
                        data.getData().toString().contains(".jpg") ||
                        data.getData().toString().contains(".jpeg")) {

                    intent.setDataAndType(data.getData(), "image/jpeg");

                } else if (data.getData().toString().contains(".doc")) {
                    intent.setDataAndType(data.getData(), "application/msword");
                } else if (data.getData().toString().contains(".docx")) {
                    intent.setDataAndType(data.getData(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                }
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

**KOTLIN**

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                type = "*/*"
                val mimeTypes = arrayOf(
                    "image/*",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
                )
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
            }
                , YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Then in the onActivityResult function:

```
if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {

                flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                if (data?.data.toString().contains(".png") ||
                    data?.data.toString().contains(".jpg") ||
                    data?.data.toString().contains(".jpeg")
                ) {
                    setDataAndType(data?.data, "image/jpeg")
                } else if (data?.data.toString().contains(".doc")) {
                    setDataAndType(data?.data, "application/msword")
                } else if (data?.data.toString().contains(".docx")) {
                    setDataAndType(
                        data?.data,
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
                    )
                }
            })
        }
```